# Do I need a transit visa for India If I have a 19 hour of layover in Delhi Airport with Air India?

Tags: india, layovers, transit-visas, afghan-citizens

My family is travelling from Kabul to Sydney via Delhi airport with Air India all the way.  We all have Afghani passports with Australian visas in them. We have a 19 hour layover in the Delhi airport. Do we need visas if we stay inside the airport and do not go outside?

Comment: Is your entire journey on a single ticket?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're flying with Air India all the way, chances are it's on a single ticket.

In this case, the rules for transit as stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=in&SECTION=vi&SUBSECTION=tw&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) apply, namely:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit
>   time of 24 hours

So no, you do **not** need an Indian visa.